# thymeleaf checkbox always sets value as false

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Method 1

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{isEnabled}"/>
   <i class="indigo"></i>
    Enable User

   <input type="hidden" value="on" name="_isEnabled"/>
</div>
```

Method 2

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="checkbox" th:checkbox="${isEnabled}" name="isEnabled"/>
   <i class="indigo"></i>
    Enable User

   <input type="hidden" value="on" name="_isEnabled"/>
</div>
```

I always get the value of `isEnabled` as `false` in the backend.

There are other fields in the form that works well. I am stuck with this checkbox part.

Comment: Is your attribute getter/setter really named `isIsEnabled`?  If the property is named `enabled`, you should be using th:field="*{enabled}"` rather than `isEnabled`.  (Also, there is no `th:checkbox` property, did you mean `th:checked`?)

Comment: The propert name is `is_enabled`. And I am using lombok for the DTO.

Comment: If the property name is `is_enabled` then the `th:field` should be `*{is_enabled}`